# Checksum error for plugin github.com/hashicorp/azure version 1.3.1

Tags: packer, hashicorp-packer

## Overview of the Issue

Hello there, I'm facing a checksum error while performing a packer init with azure plugin.

```
Failed getting the "github.com/hashicorp/azure" plugin: 1 error occurred: * could not get sha256 checksum file for github.com/hashicorp/azure version 1.3.1. Is the file present on the release and correctly named ? Get "https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/361409316/cbfe3de3-680b-4c47-b744-bbde6a784bac?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20230103%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230103T103126Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=52275607836fbd0304f7ce9d44575c6f128b4978fe43bd0c7f12e0b81e628552&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=361409316&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dpacker-plugin-azure_v1.3.1_SHA256SUMS&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

## Reproduction Steps

Use hashicorp azure plugin, I guess

## Plugin and Packer version

Azure plugin version 1.3.1
Packer version 1.8.2

## Operating system and Environment details

Packer is running on an Ubuntu WSL

## What did I tried exactly and what did I expected ?

I tried a Packer Init. Packer is supposed to initiate the plugins.

I tried to update packer, update the host, install ca-certificate. None of this resolve the issue.

Do you know how I can get away with this errors ?

Thank you :)

I tried a Packer Init. Packer is supposed to initiate the plugins.

Comment: Please add the `required_providers` block to the question.

Comment: Are you working on a network which has either a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) or a filtering [middlebox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middlebox) that might be intercepting your connections? This error suggests that your request to GitHub was redirected to a non-GitHub server and therefore the TLS authentication failed, but it doesn't seem to be Packer itself that was responsible for the request being sent to the wrong server.

Comment: Hey @MartinAtkins, thank you for the help. I add Zscaler up on the VM, it seems like it was it as I could init packer once I deactivated it. Thank you for your help and explanations.